# How to export Corel X5 figure in vector form ready for word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, documents, coreldraw

Is there solution for exporting corel vector figure in X5 to be in perfect quality for word?
Or if there is no solution how to import .pdf image to .pdf text file which is already printed from word?

Comment: Stop using Word :-) ... not the answer you are looking for, but have a look at [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#Examples) ([see also](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)). That way you can use vector graphics in documents.

Comment: @Pipe, Have you tried the "Export for Office.." wizard which saves drawing file as a vector image.

Comment: yes, but it is in .png format and I am not satisfied with quality

Answer (score 0):

I have answer to first part of your question.

as you asked:

> Is there solution for exporting corel vector figure in X5 to be in
>   perfect quality for word?

Ans: Certainly yes, and for sure you can transfer your vector figures into **Microsoft Word** without converting them totally into raster format.

**Let's start now!**

Inside **CorelDraw X5**, simply select your vector figure, **Copy** it by pressing **(Ctrl + C)**.

Now switch to **Microsoft Word** and press **(Alt + Ctrl + V)** to reveal the **Paste Special** dialog box. Select **Picture (Enhanced Metafile)** from the dialog box and click **OK** button or press **Enter** key from your keyboard.

Now you are done. This pasted image is actually **vector figure** but not with transparent background still it is **resolution free** i.e you can re-size it to make it large and it will never be distorted like bitmaps.

***Additional Info:*** As per my knowledge, **you cannot bring transparent figures** in Microsoft Word using this method. As the format to paste inside Microsoft Word, **Enhanced Meta File (emf)** is not pure vector format but it can contain vector.
[Read more about EMF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2011/06/28/emf-file-overview.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you save as soon as you've pasted into word, and then close the word file and use the open and repair option to reopen it. Then save at frequent intervals as you edit. Word tends to crash a lot after having a corel graphic pasted into it. (And vice versa).